# remove the sign at the beginning of the number - JS

Tags: javascript, slice

I am getting a calculation result minus the resulting number. When I want to remove the minus sign in front of this number, I get a ".. is not function" warning. What is the reason of this?

```
function cms(miliseconds, format) {
    let days, hours, minutes, seconds, total_hours, total_minutes, total_seconds;
    total_seconds = parseInt(Math.floor(miliseconds / 1000));
    total_minutes = parseInt(Math.floor(total_seconds / 60));
    total_hours = parseInt(Math.floor(total_minutes / 60));
    days = parseInt(Math.floor(total_hours / 24));
    seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
    minutes = parseInt(total_minutes % 60);
    hours = parseInt(total_hours % 24);
    switch (format) {
        case 's':
            return total_seconds;
        case 'm':
            return total_minutes;
        case 'h':
            return total_hours;
        case 'd':
            return days;
        default:
            return {d: days, h: hours, m: minutes, s: seconds};
    }
}

const cd3F = cms(...); // Result: -3512
cd3F.slice(1));
```

> Uncaught TypeError: cd3F.slice is not a function is not a function

Comment: Because numbers don't have a slice function. Strings do, but not numbers. If you want the absolute value of the number (that is, for instance, `23` for both `23` and `-23`), use [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs). If you want a string, convert to string (probably after `Math.abs`).

Comment: [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?retiredLocale=it) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) are a methods that you can apply to arrays or strings. Your `cms` function is returning either a number or an object. You can use `.toString()` to convert your number to string, but when it's the `default` case then you've to be clearer on your intentions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .slice method is for [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), not for numbers.

```
function cms(miliseconds, format) {
    let days, hours, minutes, seconds, total_hours, total_minutes, total_seconds;
    total_seconds = parseInt(Math.floor(miliseconds / 1000));
    total_minutes = parseInt(Math.floor(total_seconds / 60));
    total_hours = parseInt(Math.floor(total_minutes / 60));
    days = parseInt(Math.floor(total_hours / 24));
    seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
    minutes = parseInt(total_minutes % 60);
    hours = parseInt(total_hours % 24);
    switch (format) {
        case 's':
            return total_seconds;
        case 'm':
            return total_minutes;
        case 'h':
            return total_hours;
        case 'd':
            return days;
        default:
            return {d: days, h: hours, m: minutes, s: seconds};
    }
}

const cd3F = cms(...); // Result: -3512
const abs_cd3F = Math.abs(cd3F);
```

You should use [Math.abs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs). Only if it were a string, you could use .slice(1).

If you only want positive numbers then you might as well put Math.abs inside your function.

```
function cms(milliseconds, format) {
    milliseconds = Math.abs(milliseconds);
    let days, hours, minutes, seconds, total_hours, total_minutes, total_seconds;
    total_seconds = parseInt(Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000));
    total_minutes = parseInt(Math.floor(total_seconds / 60));
    total_hours = parseInt(Math.floor(total_minutes / 60));
    days = parseInt(Math.floor(total_hours / 24));
    seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
    minutes = parseInt(total_minutes % 60);
    hours = parseInt(total_hours % 24);
    switch (format) {
        case 's':
            return total_seconds;
        case 'm':
            return total_minutes;
        case 'h':
            return total_hours;
        case 'd':
            return days;
        default:
            return {d: days, h: hours, m: minutes, s: seconds};
    }
}

const cd3F = cms(-3512000, "s"); // Result: 3512
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `cms` function is either going to return a Number or an Object, and neither of them have a `slice` method.

A better function to use would be [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs), which will convert any negative number into a positive one (and leave any positive number alone) but be aware that it will return `NaN` if you pass it an object.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? `n * -1`

```js
const cd3F = cms(...); // Result: -3512
cd3F = cd3F < 0 ? cd3F * -1 : cd3F;
console.log(cd3F); // 3512
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers nor Objects have the slice method so for strings you'll first have to make the following changes

```
cd3F.slice(1));
```

to

```
cd3F.toString().slice(1) // also look at brackets
```

This doesn't solve your problem with all use cases though because you have the potential to return an object.

I'd use Math.abs() because it will return either NaN (if it is an object) or a positive integer if it is indeed a Number

Comment: Edited to also note the extra bracket